# Error in add and delete the details in the table

Tags: javascript

i am new to js i am writing a code to add and delete the details in the table? i have some error please check th code once

```js
<script>
function edit_row(no)
{
 document.getElementById("edit_button");
 document.getElementById("save_button"); 
 var name=document.getElementById("name_row"+no).value;
 var lname=document.getElementById("lname_row"+no).value;
 var country=document.getElementById("country_row"+no).value;
 var age=document.getElementById("age_row"+no);
 
 var name_data=name.innerHTML;
 var lname_data=lname.innerHTML;
 var country_data=country.innerHTML;
 var age_data=age.innerHTML;
             
 name.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='name_text"+no+"' value='"+name_data+"'>";
 lname.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='lname_text"+no+"' value='"+lname_data+"'>";
 country.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='country_text"+no+"' value='"+country_data+"'>";
 age.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='age_text"+no+"' value='"+age_data+"'>";
}

function save_row(no)
{
 var name_val=document.getElementById("name_text"+no).value;
 var lname_val=document.getElementById("lname_text"+no).value;
 var country_val=document.getElementById("country_text"+no).value;
 var age_val=document.getElementById("age_text"+no).value;

 document.getElementById("name_row"+no).innerHTML=name_val;
 document.getElementById("lname_row"+no).innerHTML=lname_val;
 document.getElementById("country_row"+no).innerHTML=country_val;
 document.getElementById("age_row"+no).innerHTML=age_val;

 document.getElementById("edit_button"+no);
 document.getElementById("save_button"+no);
}
function delete_row(no)
{
 document.getElementById("row"+no+"").innerHTML="";
}
function add_row()
{
 var new_name=document.getElementById("new_name").value;
 var new_lname=document.getElementById("new_lname").value;
 var new_country=document.getElementById("new_country").value;
 var new_age=document.getElementById("new_age").value;
 
 var table=document.getElementById("data_table");
 var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
 var row = table.insertRow(table_len).innerHTML="<tr id='row"+table_len+"'><td id='name_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_name+"</td><td id='lname_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_lname+"</td><td id='country_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_country+"</td><td id='age_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_age+"</td><td><button id='edit_button"+table_len+"' value='Edit' onclick='edit_row("+table_len+")'>Edit</button><button id='delet_button"+table_len+"' value='Delete' onclick='delet_row("+table_len+")'> Delete </button> <button id='save_button"+table_len+"' value='Save'  onclick='save_row("+table_len+")'> Save</button></td></tr>";

 document.getElementById("new_name").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_lname").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_country").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_age").value="";
}
```

```html
<table  id="data_table" border=1>
<tr>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name </th>
<th>Country</th>
<th>Age</th>
</tr>
<tr id="row1">
<td id="name_row1">sai</td>
<td id="lname_row1">Kunal</td>
<td id="country_row1">India</td>
<td id="age_row1">20</td>
<td>
<button id="edit_button"   value="Edit"   onclick="edit_row('n')">Edit</button>
<button id="save_button"   value="Save"   onclick="save_row('n')"> Save </button>
<button id="delete_button" value="Delete" onclick="delete_row('n')"> Delete</button>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="new_name" value = "" ></td>
<td><input type="text" id="new_lname" value = ""></td>
<td><input type="text" id="new_country" value = ""></td>
<td><input type="text" id="new_age" value = ""></td>
<td><button  onclick="add_row();" value="Add Row">Add Row</button> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I am getting this error please check my code and help me 
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at edit_row (addelemnts in table.html:35)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (addelemnts in table.html:17)

Comment: `Cannot read property 'value' of null
at edit_row (addelemnts in table.html:35)` - the problem is on line 35 in table.html ... something is `null` and therefore doesn't have a property called `value`

Comment: You need to replace `'n'` with the number of the row thats appended to the `id` of your `td` cells. In this case it should be `edit_row('1')`

Comment: I used your example but error is not going new error is coming Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at delete_row (addelemnts in table.html:68)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (addelemnts in table.html:19)
delete_row @ addelemnts in table.html:68
onclick @ addelemnts in table.html:19

Answer (score 0):

Below is working snippet change `onclick="save_row('n')` to `onclick="save_row('1')` and do the same for save and delete as well and on edit row function change below lines we need to find elements rather than those values so i have remove `value` from those you can read more about [.value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) of javascript

```
 var name=document.getElementById("name_row"+no);
 var lname=document.getElementById("lname_row"+no);
 var country=document.getElementById("country_row"+no);
 var age=document.getElementById("age_row"+no);
```

```js
function edit_row(no)
{
 document.getElementById("edit_button");
 document.getElementById("save_button"); 
 var name=document.getElementById("name_row"+no);
 var lname=document.getElementById("lname_row"+no);
 var country=document.getElementById("country_row"+no);
 var age=document.getElementById("age_row"+no);
 
 var name_data=name.innerHTML;
 var lname_data=lname.innerHTML;
 var country_data=country.innerHTML;
 var age_data=age.innerHTML;
             
 name.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='name_text"+no+"' value='"+name_data+"'>";
 lname.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='lname_text"+no+"' value='"+lname_data+"'>";
 country.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='country_text"+no+"' value='"+country_data+"'>";
 age.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='age_text"+no+"' value='"+age_data+"'>";
}

function save_row(no)
{
 var name_val=document.getElementById("name_text"+no).value;
 var lname_val=document.getElementById("lname_text"+no).value;
 var country_val=document.getElementById("country_text"+no).value;
 var age_val=document.getElementById("age_text"+no).value;

 document.getElementById("name_row"+no).innerHTML=name_val;
 document.getElementById("lname_row"+no).innerHTML=lname_val;
 document.getElementById("country_row"+no).innerHTML=country_val;
 document.getElementById("age_row"+no).innerHTML=age_val;

 document.getElementById("edit_button"+no);
 document.getElementById("save_button"+no);
}
function delete_row(no)
{
debugger;
 document.getElementById("row"+no+"").innerHTML="";
}
function add_row()
{
debugger;
 var new_name=document.getElementById("new_name").value;
 var new_lname=document.getElementById("new_lname").value;
 var new_country=document.getElementById("new_country").value;
 var new_age=document.getElementById("new_age").value;
 
 var table=document.getElementById("data_table");
 var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
 var row = table.insertRow(table_len);
row.id =  "row"+ table_len;
row.innerHTML= "<td id='name_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_name+"</td><td id='lname_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_lname+"</td><td id='country_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_country+"</td><td id='age_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_age+"</td><td><button id='edit_button"+table_len+"' value='Edit' onclick='edit_row("+table_len+")'>Edit</button><button id='delet_button"+table_len+"' value='Delete' onclick='delete_row("+table_len+")'> Delete </button> <button id='save_button"+table_len+"' value='Save'  onclick='save_row("+table_len+")'> Save</button></td>";

 document.getElementById("new_name").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_lname").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_country").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_age").value="";
}
```

```html
<table  id="data_table" border=1>
<tr>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name </th>
<th>Country</th>
<th>Age</th>
</tr>
<tr id="row1">
<td id="name_row1">sai</td>
<td id="lname_row1">Kunal</td>
<td id="country_row1">India</td>
<td id="age_row1">20</td>
<td>
<button id="edit_button"   value="Edit"   onclick="edit_row('1')">Edit</button>
<button id="save_button"   value="Save"   onclick="save_row('1')"> Save </button>
<button id="delete_button" value="Delete" onclick="delete_row('1')"> Delete</button>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="new_name" value = "" ></td>
<td><input type="text" id="new_lname" value = ""></td>
<td><input type="text" id="new_country" value = ""></td>
<td><input type="text" id="new_age" value = ""></td>
<td><button  onclick="add_row();" value="Add Row">Add Row</button> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: if I write like this with any .value the error is coming like this                                       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
    at edit_row (addelemnts in table.html:40)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (addelemnts in table.html:17)
edit_row @ addelemnts in table.html:40
onclick @ addelemnts in table.html:17

Comment: FInd updated answer for more info i have change in add_row function